# Tornado decoding post arugment fails with UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, tornado

Some has been using my [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) application and making POST requests which contain this character: `¡`

Tornado was unable to decode the value and ended up with this error: HTTP 400: Bad Request (Invalid unicode in PARAMNAME: b'DATAHERE')

So I made some investigation and learned that In request body, I was receiving `%A1` for the corresponding character, which python's `decode` method had no difficulty to decode for `utf-8` encoding.

But, after URL-decoding this value, Tornado ended up with `\xa1` for the character and tried to decode this using utf-8 and failed, because this was actually **ISO-8859-1** encoding.

So, what should be the appropriate way to fix this? Because user is sending valid output I don't want to loose this data.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to make sure the client always sends utf8 instead of iso8859-1 (this used to require weird tricks like the rails snowman; I'm not sure about the current state of the art).  If you cannot do that, override RequestHandler.decode_argument (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.decode_argument), which can see the raw bytes and decide how to decode them (or pass them through unchanged if you don't want to decode at this point).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually solved this problem by overriding `decode_argument`. But I was thinking, If Python bytes decode method could decode the character mentioned above successfully for utf-8 encoding shouldn't Tornado be able to decode the character successfully?